# How can I create a number range filter in react table v7?

Tags: react-table, react-table-v7

How can I create a number range filter in react table v7? Here is my relevant column definition, and filter function.

```
// The Filter function
import { Box, Input } from '@mui/material';
    const NumberFilter = ({ column, data }) => {
        const { filterValue = [], setFilter } = column;
        console.log('filterValue: ' + filterValue);
        return (
            <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                <Input
                    placeholder="Min"
                    value={filterValue[0] || ''}
                    type="number"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        setFilter([e.target.value || undefined, filterValue[1]]);
                    }}
                />
                <Input
                    placeholder="Max"
                    value={filterValue[1] || ''}
                    type="number"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        setFilter([filterValue[0], e.target.value || undefined]);
                    }}
                />{' '}
            </Box>
        );
    };
    export default NumberFilter;




// The column definition...
{
 Header: 'Pant Size',
 accessor: 'pant-size',
 Filter: NumberFilter,
 filter: 'isNumberRange',
 filterValue: [0, 10],
 Cell: ({ value}) => value);
}
```

This does not work. Instead of filtering all rows that have a value within the range of min and max, the column seems to be doing text matching, which is the default.

I think my issue is that there are various options for the filter parameter. For example, 'text' and 'exact'. I read somewhere that there is an option for numeric ranges and it was "isNumberRange". This clearly is incorrect. Is there another option? Does anyone know where this documentation lives?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [filterTypes source code](https://github.com/TanStack/table/blob/v7/src/filterTypes.js), the list of filterTypes supported by default are:

- *text* (default): the value of a cell in the row as a String has the filter value as a substring
- *exactText*: the value of a cell in the row as a String has the filter value exactly, case-insensitive
- *exactTextCase*: the value of a cell in the row as a String has the filter value exactly, case-sensitive
- *includes*: the value of a cell in the row has the filter value as one of its elements (returned by `value.includes(filterValue)`)
- *includesAll*: every cell in the row is valid for a list of filter values
- *includesSome*: at least one cell in the row is valid for a list of filter values
- *includesValue*: the value of a cell in the row is part of a filter value (`filterValue.includes(value)`)
- *exact*: the value of a cell in the row is === equal to the filter value
- *equals*: the value of a cell is == equal to the filter value
- *between*: if the filter value has a 'min' or 'max' attribute, then at least one cell in the row is greater than or equal to the 'min' and less than or equal to the 'max'; if either 'min' or 'max' are missing, then assume negative/positive Infinity.

For this use case, the 'between' filterType would be most appropriate.